# No constituent of type 'true | CallableFunction' is callable

Tags: javascript, typescript

The full error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'true | CallableFunction' is callable
```

This is the code that was triggering the error:

```
public static base(
    text,
    callB: boolean | CallableFunction = false,
    
  ) {
    const sw = Swal.fire({
      text,
      });

    if (callB) {
      sw.then(callB());
    }
  }
```

I changed the type of callB to :

```
 callB: (param: any) => void |boolean = false
```

and when I remove the callB type definition:

```
callB= false
```

I get this error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures
```

Comment: how exactly you are calling `base` method?

Comment: Is `boolean` a return type of the function in the type of `callB`? A boolean value is not callable because it is not a function.

Comment: `callB` is an optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```js
function base(text: string, callB: false | CallableFunction = false) {
  console.log(text);
  if (callB) {
    callB();
  }
}
```

Essentially, you want to pass a function or `false`. When it is truthy you want to call the function.

But as per your definition

```js
function base(text: string, callB: boolean | CallableFunction = false) {
  console.log(text);
  if (callB) {
    callB();
  }
}
```

this would be a valid call `base('some str', true)` where `callB` is `true` and not a function that it will try to execute using `callB()`. Not boolean is not callable, it is? Hence the error.

TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/m056qW

Comment: This is what I want. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The type

```
boolean | Function
```

is equivalent to

```
true | false | Function
```

Now because a value of type `Function` is truthy, your check

```
if (callB)
```

narrows the type of `callB` to

```
true | Function
```

and `true` is not callable, hence the error.

It's not clear how your `base` method is meant to be used so I've outlined two solutions:

If `true` isn't a valid input, adjust your parameter type accordingly

```
static base(
    text, 
    callB: false | CallableFunction = false
) {
    if (callB) {
        callB();
    }
}
```

If `true` is a case you must handle, use a more precise conditional check such as

```
if (typeof callB === 'function') {
    callB() // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `false | Callablefunction` (or `boolean | CallableFunction`) , you can coerce type by using `typeof`:

```
static base(
    text,
    callB: false | CallableFunction = false
) {
    if (typeof callB === "function") {
        callB()
    }
}
```